# Finding maxmin equilibrium in a game

Tags: game-theory

I was solving for a stable equilibrium in the following 2 player zero sum game. I need to calculate the equilibrium using maxmin and minmax strategies. In this game they should come out to be identical and coincide with the mixed strategy Nash's equilibrium.

```
                            P2
                   L                R
       L       (0.6,0.4)         (0.8,0.2)
```

P1

```
      R        (0.9,0.1)         (0.7,0.3)
```

If I solve it formally, the expected payoff of P1 will be the expression:

***E = { 0.6(pq) + 0.8p(1-q) + 0.9(1-p)(q) + 0.7(1-p)(1-q) }***

where p is probability of P1 playing L and q is the probability pf P2 playing L. Now, P2 is trying to minimize E keeping in mind that P1 is trying to maximize it

i.e. min max {E}

and P1 is trying to maximize E keeping in mind that P1 will try to minimize E 
i.e.

max min {E}

and vice versa.
Essentially both strategies played simultaneously should give the same equilibrium. How to go about it, I am stuck in the maths part of the problem now.

Comment: In game theory, each player acts according to how each other player acts. So we need to know the expected payoffs of both players. It would help if you gave us the original question and conditions for the game as well. Could you edit your question with this information?

Comment: Are you sure you need a stable equilibrium? Mixed equilibria of matrix games are never stable. In case you just need to find the mixed Nash equilibrium I found very useful resources by googling " mixed Nash equilibrium".
http://oyc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/mixed_strategies_handout_0.pdf
http://www.tayfunsonmez.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/E308SL7.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate and the "close as duplicate" function isn't working properly at the present moment.